# Why $p \lor (\lnot p \land q)$ is not equal to $(p \lor \lnot p) \land q$ ? I had trying making Truth Table but, still can't figure it out?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Why $p \lor (\lnot p \land q)$ is not equal to $(p \lor \lnot p) \land q$ ? I had trying making Truth Table but, still can't figure it out ?

Comment: By $\sim$ do you mean $\lnot$?

Comment: Because the first one is equiv to $(p \lor \lnot p) \land (p \lor q)$. See [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic).

Comment: But by, Assosiative Law we can change that Bracket thing ??? so why they are not true???

Comment: Note that you have two different operations $\land$ and $\lor$. We don't have associativity with these two different operations. It might help you to compare it with $+,\cdot$. For example $(4+2)\cdot 3 \not = 4+(2\cdot 3)$.

Comment: Got it. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ is true then the first is automatically true. If $q$ is false then the second is automatically false.

I have no idea what you mean by $\sim$ but it doesn't even matter.

Answer (score 2):

The statement $p\vee\neg p$ is a true statement in Boolean algebra.

Then:

$$p\vee(\neg p\wedge q)=(p\vee\neg p)\wedge(p\vee q)=p\vee q$$by distribution and:$$(p\vee\neg p)\wedge q=q$$

If you are approaching with truth tables then you encounter the difference for $q=0$ and $p=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$(p\vee\sim p)\wedge q=1\wedge q=q\because p\vee\sim p=1$

$p∨(\sim p∧q)=p\vee q$ by the Absorption law.

Try $p=1,q=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The term $(p\vee\neg p)\vee q$ is equivalent to $q$ since term in parenthesis is logically true.

The term $p\vee (\neg p\wedge q)$ has the truth value $1$ if $p=1$ independent of the value of $q$.